# window.location.href javascript does not trigger shouldOverrideUrlLoading

Tags: android

My tested on nexous one (compiled with android 2.2) shows that shouldOverrideUrlLoading is not triggered when the page is redirected via window.location.href. The onPageFinished is trigger as usual.

Could anyone advise how to intercept javascript page redirect? 
Any other way to redirect the page in javascript so shouldOverrideUrlLoading is triggered?
Is this a bug for shouldOverrideUrlLoading?

Thanks,

June

Answer (score 1):

In my case, when using `window.location = "http://xxx"` in my webpage, the event `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` is not triggered.

However, if I use a custom url scheme or protocol such as `androidurl://`, `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` is fired. My workaround would to be use a custom protocol and add the following code in the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` method:

```
if (url.startsWith("androidurl://")) {
    url = url.replaceAll("androidurl://", "http://");
}
```

This will change the custom protocol back to the `http://` protocol and you can handle the correct url from there.

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

> Could anyone advise how to intercept javascript page redirect?

Modify the Javascript to call a method on some object you inject into `WebView` via `addJavascriptInterface()`.

> Is this a bug for shouldOverrideUrlLoading?

Possibly. It is certainly a limitation.

Comment: It is a bug, because if you change location.href, u do literally load an URL. So by overriding this and handle everything, you should be able to be sure there is no other URL loading at all. People assume WebView is only to display their own pages. But consider you want to render remote sites, and do not control the javascript running...

Comment: @CommonsWare can you tell me how can i get url when i am loading view inside div tags.. and using only one index.html and loading other file data into that div tag of index file..at this condition how can i get url

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use ***WebChromeClient***'s ***onJsBeforeUnload()*** to intercept the event that you're about to leave current page. Override *onJsBeforeUnload()* and set a flag to *true*.

Then use ***WebViewClient***'s ***onLoadResource()*** to intercept the URL to be loaded. If flag is *true*, do whatever you want, e.g. open the URL in another *Intent*; otherwise do nothing.

Also, remember to add to your HTML:

```
<script> window.onbeforeunload = function(){  
   return "Leave?";  
}; </script>
```