# WebView addJavascriptInterface - How to use?

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-webview, dom-events

I'm trying to fire a Java function residing in a HTML document that is loaded in my webView via an ImageButton on my title bar within my Android activity.  I followed the help docs but I'm not getting it.

Can someone please correct my script; it would be a big help and more to learn off of.

The function in the HTML doc (mWebView):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        function ToC(){
            $.mobile.changePage("docs/ToC.html", "slideup");
        };
    });
</script>
```

...and the code in my .main activity (main.java):

```
public class main extends Activity {

    WebView mWebView;
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

// -- Called when the activity is first created. --/
    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.window_title);
           if (savedInstanceState != null)
                    ((WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1)).restoreState(savedInstanceState);

// -- Set up the WebView -->
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new myJavaScriptInterface(), "jsi");
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new myWebViewClient());
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

    final class myJavaScriptInterface {

        myJavaScriptInterface() {

        ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bookBtn);
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                    mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:ToC()");
                    }
                });
                }
            });
        }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.mobile.changePage("docs/ToC.html", "slideup");
```

Assuming this modifies `window.location.href` or something similar, it would appear that perhaps this does not trigger `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`. See [window.location.href javascript does not trigger shouldOverrideUrlLoading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502285/window-location-href-javascript-does-not-trigger-shouldoverrideurlloading/5503262) for more, including my suggested workaround.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late, but note that `myJavaScriptInterface()` never gets called, so the button's OnClickListener is never set, so the button won't do anything.

A javascript interface is for communication from javascript into your app; its methods are only called where you explicitly call them in your javascript.  In order to call `myJavaScriptInterface()`, you'd put somewhere in your javascript: `jsi.myJavaScriptInterface();`.  Presumably you'd put it in a place where you'd want the button's handler to be set, like maybe in `$(document).ready()`.  Personally, I'd just set the handler in the main code, without the interface, but your way probably works, too.